# how to check out from svn using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, tortoisesvn

I am using Eclipse for PHP Developers Version: 3.0.2. How could I check out from a remote svn(TortoiseSVN). I googled online, but it did help, I tried to import, but there is no such option as 'from svn'.

Answer (score 0):

You might not have the svn plugin for eclipse installed.You could download it from here.
http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/latest-releases.php

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have the option to "Checkout Projects from SVN" you are probably missing the SVN plugin. @Arcane posted a link to download the plugin and [HERE](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ecl-subversion/)[[1](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ecl-subversion/)] is a link to a full description how to use the plugin.

[[1](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ecl-subversion/)] : http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ecl-subversion/